# What VBA objects can I use for reference?

Tags: vba, object

For a basic function that creates an object variable, what kinds of objects can I refer to that appear in a userform?

For example, I know that

```
    Dim button As CommandButton
    Set button = CommandButton1
    button.Caption = "Text I can change for this object."
```

Will run and change properties of CommanButton1. This does not seem to work for labels or textboxes in userforms due to a mismatch error. Is there a list of objects usable in this fashion, and is there a way I can use labels or textboxes like this for arrays?

Comment: Try using the value property (I think) for textboxes. What do you mean "use labels or textboxes like this for arrays"? Can you be a little clearer?

Comment: You probably need to add a little more context around what you're trying to do. `Me.CommandButton1.Caption="blah"` is the simpler approach. Or `Me.Controls("CommandButton1").Caption`   If you use the latter one then as long as the named control has a `Caption` property it should work.

Comment: Ideally I would like to have an array of my labels in a userform that I can access. I have seen loops that go through each control in a page, but I would prefer to have a reference for each individual object for my own arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you indicated in your comment that you are looking for arrays by type, for a userform... Here is a rough draft of an example that would work for labels (`MsForms.Label`). It still loops through all of the controls, but once the array is created you can use it freely.

```
Option Explicit
Private labels() As MSForms.label

Private Sub PopulateLabelArray()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim count As Long
    Dim lbl As Variant
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.label Then
        count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim labels(1 To count)
    count = 0
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.label Then
            count = count + 1
            Set labels(count) = ctrl
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lbl As variant
    'Populate the label array.
    PopulateLabelArray
    'Test the array
    For Each lbl In labels()
    Debug.Print lbl.Caption
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm sure this could be improved on, but this is functional.

Comment: This is what I need! Thanks much. Small error when I ran it, lbl under UserForm_Initialize needs to be type variant. Otherwise this works for my labels and textboxes, thank you.

Comment: The funny part is that I found that error when I was testing, fixed it and then still gave you the error. Oops. Glad it worked as you wanted.